# How to put space between barcode and text using barcode widget package?

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode

as you can see in the image the barcode and data text don't have space and I don't know how to put space in this barcode widget I'm using [barcode widget](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_widget)

[image]

here is my code and im required to use code39 type of barcode

```
class Barcode extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
  children: [
    BarcodeWidget(
      barcode: Barcode.code39(),
      data: '0912658792',
      width: size(480),
      height: size(120),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: size(60),
      ),
    ),
    BarcodeWidget(
      barcode: Barcode.code39(),
      data: '195795296',
      width: size(480),
      height: size(120),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60)),
    ),
    BarcodeWidget(
      barcode: Barcode.code39(),
      data: '4952687794',
      width: size(480),
      height: size(120),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60)),
    ),
  ],
);
}
}`
```

I really appreciate if someone help me, or recommend me other barcode package that can put space under the barcode, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This:    

class Barcode extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
      children: [
        BarcodeWidget(
          barcode: Barcode.code39(),
          data: '\n 0912658792',
          width: size(480),
          height: size(120),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: size(60),
            top: size(60)
          ),
        ),
        BarcodeWidget(
          barcode: Barcode.code39(),
          data: '\n 195795296',
          width: size(480),
          height: size(120),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60),top: size(60)),
        ),
        BarcodeWidget(
          barcode: Barcode.code39(),
          data: '\n 4952687794',
          width: size(480),
          height: size(120),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60),top: size(60)),
        ),
      ],
    );
    }
    }`
```

Comment: this margin is for the whole barcode widget not the text widget only, so if i use this the barcode and the data text under the barcode are not gonna change

Comment: i have also edited my answer kindly check this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SizedBox between the different BarcodeWidget instances.

```
... (your earlier code here)
...
children: [
    BarcodeWidget(
      barcode: Barcode.code39(),
      data: '0912658792',
      width: size(480),
      height: size(120),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: size(60),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 40,
    ),
    BarcodeWidget(
      barcode: Barcode.code39(),
      data: '195795296',
      width: size(480),
      height: size(120),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60)),
    ),
...
...
```

Comment: no, what i want is the space between the barcode and the data under the barcode, not the space between each barcode widget

Comment: That may be part of the barcode specification, and cannot be changed without invalidating the standard.

Answer (score 0):

i figure out the answer

```
 BarcodeWidget(
  barcode: Barcode.code39(),
  data: '195795296',
  width: size(480),
  height: size(120),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: size(60)),
  style: TextStyle(height: 2.0),
),
```

add style with height to get the space that i want